# Unable to select image with custom field

Tags: custom-field, images

I'm using the [advanced custom field plugin](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) to convert WP into a CMS (it's works brilliantly for this). There's just one issue - with an image field it's not quite a smooth process as images need to be selected twice, this causes user confusion.

Rather than me up all the images again - please see [here](http://support.plugins.elliotcondon.com/discussion/188/image-field-not-inserting-image) for step by step process of the problem.

I'm not sure if this is a WP problem or a problem with the plugin.

Comment: Why do you keep saying "convert WP into a CMS"? WordPress *already is a CMS out of the box*.

Comment: It's not really, someone couldn't just pick it up and use it like a full cms! Why are you getting so hung up on the wording!

Comment: Pet peeve, mostly - but also, accuracy.

Comment: adding CMS in all your question titles is pointless and doesn't really add to understanding or solving your problems, on the contrary it adds confusion. CMS = content management system. I manage content with WP, hence it is a CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been solved.

It was a case of fixing the http error I was getting with the flash uploader. It then gives you the select button rather than the insert into post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very Plugin-specific question, for which you're already getting support responses from the Plugin's developer. I'm not sure anyone here would know the Plugin any better than would the developer.

That said: if I'm reading the developer's support responses correctly, I think he's saying that you need to upload the image via the media manager, and *save changes*, rather than *insert into post*. Then, you can select the image from the *Library* tab, once it's been uploaded and saved.

What are the "image" custom fields being used for? Additional "Featured" images, or something?

Comment: Firstly, I'm not sure if it's a WP problem or a plugin problem, hence the question. Via the media manager is one way but seeing how it's being used by the clients, it's not ideal.